# How to make SVG in ::before pseudo-class clickable?

Tags: svg, breadcrumbs, pseudo-class

I have a breadcrumb that lists the page's hierarchy path. I hid the first anchor tag & changed the anchor tag `::before` pseudo-class to an SVG of a small house like so:

```
li:first-child a {
    display: none;
  }

li:first-child::before {
    color: transparent;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: rem(16px);
    height: rem(16px);
    position: relative;
    top: rem(2px);
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("../images/breadcrumb-image.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    &:hover {
      color: transparent;
    }
  }
```

I got the desire effect but the SVG is not clickable to return to the home page. Any solutions for this? I don't mind whether CSS or JS.

This is the image so it gives you an idea:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to make the SVG on a `::before` pseudo-class clickable through jQuery like so:

**SCSS Code:**

This is the styling to hide the anchor tag & add an SVG to the anchor tag before pseudo-class.

```
li:first-child a {
    display: none;
  }
li:first-child::before {
    color: transparent;
    content: '';
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: rem(16px);
    height: rem(16px);
    position: relative;
    top: rem(2px);
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("../images/breadcrumb-image.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    &:hover {
      color: transparent;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
  //Store the href attribute(the link was already pointing to the home page) of the anchor tag in a variable
  var breadcrumbHomeLink = $('.breadcrumb__list--item:first-child a').attr('href');

  //Store the SVG with ::before pseudo-class in variable
  var breadcrumbSVG = $('.breadcrumb__list--item:first-child').before();

  //Make Breadcrumb SVG clickable & redirect to home page
  breadcrumbSVG.on('click', function(){
    location.href = breadcrumbHomeLink;
  });
```